# Oracle - Cursor

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Estou estudando PL/SQL e testando o uso de CURSOR, porém não estou conseguindo testar um exemplo:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
  V_NAME VARCHAR2(50);
  CURSOR CUR_CURSOR IS
    SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES;
  TEMP CUR_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  IF NOT CUR_CURSOR%ISOPEN THEN
    OPEN CUR_CURSOR;
    LOOP
      FETCH CUR_CURSOR INTO TEMP;
      EXIT
    WHEN CUR_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_NAME);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CUR_CURSOR;
END;
```

Erro:

> Relatório de erros -
>       ORA-06550: linha 17, coluna 1:
>       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
>
> ```
>    if
> 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
> *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
> *Action:
> ```

Comment: veja se todos os comandos de estrutura tem início e vim na ordem quer foram declarados, veja `begin, if, open, loop` etc

Answer (score 1):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  V_NAME VARCHAR2(50);
  CURSOR CUR_CURSOR IS
    SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES;
  TEMP CUR_CURSOR%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  IF NOT CUR_CURSOR%ISOPEN THEN
    OPEN CUR_CURSOR;
    LOOP
      FETCH CUR_CURSOR INTO TEMP;
      EXIT
    WHEN CUR_CURSOR%NOTFOUND;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(V_NAME);
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE CUR_CURSOR;
  END IF;
END;
```

Um outro jeito (mais simples)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

BEGIN
  FOR REMP IN (SELECT FIRST_NAME FROM EMPLOYEES)
  LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(REMP.FIRST_NAME);
  END LOOP;
END;
```